# Can't find the driver for a usb wi-fi dongle (linux)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I bought a cheap wifi usb adapter that said it's compatible with linux. 
I did `lsusb`
and it says

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0408:03f1 Quanta Computer, Inc.
```

I searched for 'quanta' in apt, but there aren't any drivers for it. 
Is it possible to find the driver by the ID?

Comment: quanta is probably the company that built it - I don't think they make chipsets. Some more information on what it is might help?

Comment: Is any wifi interface reported by `/sbin/ifconfig`? [If in doubt check ifconfig output with and without  device plugged. Wait a few seconds after plugin the device ]  It is possible that the device is handled by some general driver.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu's WiFi adapter trouble-shooting page, https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Comment: Are you **sure** `0408:03f1` is the ID of your cheap wifi adapter? Googling for that ID only shows references where some *other* Wifi adapter is present. Can you verify that this line disappears when your wifi adapter is *not* plugged in? And please edit your questions with the lines in `dmesg` that appear after you plug it in.